# CSS Not Applied to Node Added by JS appendChild

Tags: javascript, html, css

My html:

```
<div id=Info>
        <p>Id: <span>001</span></p>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#Info p {
    font-weight: bold;
}

#Info span {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

My JS code:

```
var pElement = document.createElement('p');
var spanElement = document.createElement("span");
var elementValue1 = document.createTextNode("Id: ");
var elementValue2 = document.createTextNode("003");
spanElement.appendChild(elementValue1);
pElement.appendChild(elementValue2);
pElement.appendChild(spanElement);
document.querySelector('#Info').appendChild(pElement);
```

CSS style applied correctly to the line:`<p>Id: <span>001</span></p>` from html file. But somehow, CSS style is not applied to the node added by appendChild from JS file. I couldn't figure out why.
I'm new to html/CSS/JS, any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is seems to be qworking perfectly fine, but there are multiple issues in shared code.

1. CSS is referring to `#bookInfo` as opposed to `#Info`
2. You are appending `elementValue1` to `spanElement` as opposed to `elementValue2`.

Let's look at fixed code:

```js
var pElement = document.createElement('p');
var spanElement = document.createElement("span");
var elementValue1 = document.createTextNode("Id: ");
var elementValue2 = document.createTextNode("003");
spanElement.appendChild(elementValue2);
pElement.appendChild(elementValue1);
pElement.appendChild(spanElement);
document.querySelector('#Info').appendChild(pElement);
```

```css
#Info p {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#Info span {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<div id=Info>
  <p>Id: <span>001</span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the div id is not match between your html and the css.
In the html, the `id=Info` should be `id="bookInfo"`

Answer (score 1):

not a good way to do it but here is your code:

https://jsfiddle.net/r6j31zhL/

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="Info">
    <p>Id: <span>001</span></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<style>
#Info p {
font-weight: bold;
}

#Info span {
font-weight: normal;
}
</style>
<script>
var pElement = document.createElement('p');
var spanElement = document.createElement("span");
var elementValue1 = document.createTextNode("Id: ");
var elementValue2 = document.createTextNode("003");
spanElement.appendChild(elementValue2);
pElement.appendChild(elementValue1);
pElement.appendChild(spanElement);
document.querySelector('#Info span').appendChild(pElement);
</script>
```